# Azure Video Indexer stuck on 5%

Tags: azure, azure-video-indexer

I am trying to use the Azure Video Indexer. I uploaded a 40 MB video before and it worked with no issues. However, I tried to upload two videos one that is 250 MB video the other is 980 MB and it they both stall at 5% processing. It has been more than 12 hours and they haven't gone past 5%.

I'm using the following code to upload videos, I am passing links to mp4 videos on s3.

```py
def upload_video(account_id: str, account_location: str, account_access_token: str, api_url: str, video_info: dict):
    query_params = urlencode({
        "accessToken": account_access_token,
        "name": video_info['name'],
        "description": video_info['description'],
        "privacy": "private",
        "partition": "partition",
        # Do not include VideoUrl when uploading Video using StreamContent
        "videoUrl": video_info['url'],
    })


    try:
        response = requests.post(
            url=f'{api_url}/{account_location}/Accounts/{account_id}/Videos?{query_params}')
        response = response.json()
        return response
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))
        raise
```